# Proper punctuation for joining pro-sentence with independent clause

Tags: punctuation

I recently said the following in chat:

> Do you mean 90 cents, or 9 cents?
>   90 cents.
>   Okay, you left out the zero so I wasn't sure.

Afterwards it occurred to me I could have replaced the comma with a semi-colon. This led to a discussion with @ArdaXi over what the correct punctuation mark to use in this situation is: a comma, semi-colon, or period. The uncertainty arises from the fact that *okay* is a [pro-sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-sentence).

What is the proper punctuation to use when joining a pro-sentence with an independent clause?

Comment: What do you mean by "pro-sentence"? This isn't an English grammatical term that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Why do I always seem to stir up questions on this site?

Comment: @JSBᾶngs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-sentence

Comment: I've added more context to my question

Comment: I think that Wikipedia page is a bit of a waste of space. I also think that "okay" *could* have been a sentence in OP's example, *had it been followed by a full-stop*. Since it wasn't, it's not. Finally, I think it *should* have been written as a sentence in its own right, since it's effectively shorthand for "I understand".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The punctuation after *okay* is correct. Sentence-initial particles such as *okay*, *well*, *so*, etc. are written with a following comma.

> Well, we decided to move.
>
> So, it seems like John has to get a new care.

In your case, I'd say that you're missing a comma after *zero* and an additional pronoun:

> Okay, you left out the zero **,** so **I** wasn't sure.

Comment: The I was a mistake on my part. I edited it into my original sentence.

Comment: I suppose it's a moot point what if anything *"Okay"* means in OP's example. I read it as *"I understand."*, but I guess you're reading it as *"Well yes, but..."*

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper punction to use when joining a pro-sentence with an independent clause?

It depends on the relevance of the first and second sentence. If the first and second sentence are very closely related, then a comma is used. If the first and second sentences are not that closely related, but still related, a semicolon is used, to show that they are not very closely related, but not separate enough to be entire new sentences.

Examples:

> John took an apple, and as a result, all the apples fell from the cart.
>   John took an apple; Katie took an apple too.

However, in your sentence, *okay* is not a previous sentence, or an independent clause. It's more  of a [discourse particle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_particle). In this case, a comma would be used.

Comment: Hm, according to wikipedia, discourse particle has no direct semantic meaning in the context (examples: well, y'know, like). I agree that 'okay' *can* be a discourse particle, but it can also semantically stand for 'yes I agree' or 'I understand' in which case it can not be a discourse particle (I believe this is the case here - he agrees with what was previously said and explains why he objected or questioned).

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't make Okay an independent clause

Comment: How not? If we take it to mean 'yes I agree with what you said', then for sure - it can stand independently. He could have said only 'Okay.' Also, wikipedia lists it as an example of pro-sentence (along with *yes*, *no* and *amen*) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-sentence

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, if 'okay' is indeed a pro-sentence in your example (if the previous sentence was something like "The number should be one thousand, not one hundred."), then I would say you are missing a semicolon.  If the 'okay' in your example is not [anaphorically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_%28linguistics%29) linked to previous information then it would qualify as a discourse particle and should be used with a comma like any other.